# Programmatic interface to Quartz CronExpression?

Tags: parsing, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Is there something in the [Quartz libraries](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/index.html) that provides programmatic access to the fields in a CronExpression?

It seems odd (and rather error-prone) if I can only create a CronExpression with a string to parse instead of with getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

Old but worth to be answered. You may have a look at [org.quartz.TriggerUtils](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/) to get some programatically support on this subject. But if you have a close look at the source, you will find something like `trig.setCronExpression(String);`. So finally, the quartzs guys do the expression building for you.